# При работе с Bitmap изображение переворачивается и отражается

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

Привет!

Возникла необходимость считать .bmp изображение (ч/б 50х67 пикс.) попиксельно и записать в файл( 1 - черный пиксель, 0 - белый пиксель). Получил ширину, высоту запустил циклы и в результате получил перевернутую на 90 градусов и отраженную по оси х картинку.  Цикл считывания ниже:

```
        var img =  new Bitmap(pb.Image);
        img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipX);
        var w = img.Width;
        var h = img.Height;
        var n = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < w; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(" ");

            for (var j = 0; j < h; j++)
            {
                var pix = img.GetPixel(i, j).R;
                if (pix <= 250)
                    n = "1";
                else n = "0";

                listBox1.Items[i] += Convert.ToString(n);

            }

        }
```

[Скрин тут](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHZFw.png)

Хорошо, что есть img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipX);

Но все-таки почему так произошло? Это особенности работы c Bitmap?

Comment: а можете показать как считывали ?

Comment: @FoggyFinder в вопрос добавил

Comment: Скриншоты не помешают)

Comment: @ArtikSlayer добавил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Параметры местами поменяйте.

```
img.GetPixel(j, i).R;
```

Ну и поворот, естественно, уберите.

Comment: Тогда уж и пределы в циклах стоит поменять

Comment: Да, действительно.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за ответы. Ошибка была в цикле: внешний цикл нужно по height, а внутренний по width пускать.